# adding tag to a specific page

Tags: layout, xml, html

hello everyone i have added a specific tag to all page of my website , but I want to add it to just the home page , can i achieve that ?

i have added the meta tag like below, but it appears on all website's pages when i inspect "View page source"

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="......" content="...." />
    </head>
</page>
```

can i add it only on home page ?

Answer (score 1):

To change the layout of the home page only add your changes to the layout template `cms_index_index.xml`

In this example I am using a template `metahome.phtml` in a `My_Seo` module to add custom meta tags to the home page header.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * SEO Index page layout
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="meta.home" template="My_Seo::metahome.phtml"></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```